# Prove that removing an open neighbourhood $V$ of a knot $K$ in $S^3$ does not affect the connectedness of the complement, $S^3 \backslash V$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, knot-theory

I saw that answer: [$W$ be an $m$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ such that $m\le n-2$ , then is it true that $\mathbb R^n \setminus W$ is connected?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183261/w-be-an-m-dimensional-linear-subspace-of-mathbb-rn-such-that-m-le-n-2), but I am not sure how can I apply it to $S^3$ or rather: if I can apply this. Does it somehow follow from the one-point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: One needs to impose stronger conditions. If one chooses points $p, q \in S^3 - K$, then, $V := S^3 - \{p, q\}$ is an open neighborhood of $K$, but $S^3 - V = \{p, q\}$ is not connected.

Comment: Perhaps the claim is that one *can* choose an open neighborhood $V$ of $K$ such that $S^3 - V$ is connected?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about some small tubular neighbourhood.